# iOS build error when using Google Sign-In

Tags: codenameone

I get the following iOS build error when I use Google Sign-In in my app:

```
CocoaPods 1.7.4 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.7.4

Process return code is 0
Executing: /usr/local/bin/pod install Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Bolts (1.9.0)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (4.39.1)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit (4.39.1)
Installing FBSDKShareKit (4.39.1)
Installing googleplus-ios-sdk (1.7.1)

[!] Error installing googleplus-ios-sdk
[!] /usr/bin/unzip /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/d20190711-62890-uo1yd3/file.zip -d /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/d20190711-62890-uo1yd3

Archive:  /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/d20190711-62890-uo1yd3/file.zip
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/d20190711-62890-uo1yd3/file.zip or
    /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/d20190711-62890-uo1yd3/file.zip.zip, and cannot find /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/d20190711-62890-uo1yd3/file.zip.ZIP, period.
Process return code is 1
Cocoapods failed even after updating master repo
```

I don't get this error if I remove the /native/ios/GoogleService-Info.plist file

Comment: We need the full error log to track these sort of errors. Please use our on-site chat support and provide the link for the full build error